# Не работает bower, что делать

Tags: javascript

В git, установил bower с помощью npm i -s bower
Далее пишу bower-c или подобные команды и пишет bower: not found command, что делать?

Comment: вы установили bower локально

Answer (score 1):

Это из-за того, что вы установили его не глобально. Для этого нужно:

```
npm i -g bower
```

И тогда он будет доступен.

Или если вам все таки нужно устанавливать его `node_modules` текущего проекта, то можно писать так:

```
npx bower
```

P.S. `bower` уже считается устаревшим и `npm` при установке выдает (возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону других пакетов):

> We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/